# Flutter responsive design approach

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, flutter-layout, responsive

I'm new to flutter and i have no prior experience in app development.
as far as i know there are two methods for responsive design.

1. designing relative to screen size.
2. design separate layouts for different screen size or break point!

which one is better? are there any pros and cons that can help to choose between of these designing methods?
simplicity or maintenance are not my concerns, the overall app performance is important to me.

[image: small device]
[image: large device]

Comment: In most examples I saw they used second option.

Answer (score 1):

It's the best to use similar sizes on different screens. Flutter uses logical pixels which are independent on resolution and screen ratio of the device. So `Container` with 100 width and 100 height takes the same physical space on 4 inch screen and 7 inch screen.
In vertical orientation it's common to set widgets to use whole width but only some pixels in height and put this widget in `ListView`. This way on bigger screens you can fit more widgets, but on all of them widgets should take similar space.
Also, sometimes developers support horizontal orientation with different arrangement of widgets.

Comment: maybe my question was unclear. in container example, i want it occupy same fraction of screen in all screen sizes!
(i added 2 images in my post, small and large screen that represent 100x100 container)

Comment: @FrozenForest If you want to occupy the same fraction of the screen set width and height as some fraction of `MediaQuery.size`. But It's wrong to have everything related to screen size. For instance you don't want to have bigger font size on bigger screens.

Comment: actually i want to make some parts of app related to screen not all of them. i wanted to know if sizing elements like this (width: screenSize * 0.25) wont produce any issue, i use it otherwise i make different layout for each break point.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is that you use relative measures, and widgets like Expanded, Flexible, MediaQuery, FittedBox... among others more advanced, like studying about Constraints in Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing Ui for multiple screen sizes you can write Ui only once with the help of this package [flutter_next](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_next) And it has some cool extension for rapid UI Developement and the documentation is also good.

They even have an example which is made with this package
[Demo](https://one-page-with-flutter.netlify.app/)